# Switching view controller from a tabbar item according to condition

Tags: objective-c, segue, tabbar

in my iOS 7+ app, I have a 4 items UITabBarController. One of these items needs to segue to a viewController_A **or** a viewController_B, according to certain conditions (myCondition).

I have a TabBarController class, where I've already set the logic according to myCondition to change item.image and item.title. The code works fine but I don't know how to send item1 to viewController_A **or** viewController_B

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
```

[some more code here]

```
if (myCondition) {
        item1.selectedImage = myItemImageSel_B;
        item1.image= myItemImage_B;
        item1.title= myItemTitle_B;
    }
    else
    {
        item1.selectedImage = myItemImageSel_A;
        item1.image= myItemImage_A;
        item1.title= myItemTitle_A;
    }
```

The segues are currently set through the storyboard for all the 4 items.

Am I using the correct approach? Or should I just add a new item to viewController_B and hide it until my condition is true?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well one approach you can do is just set the tag value inside your `tabview` and use `switch case statement` rather than using `if else condition`. Also it will be more faster.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by setting the tag value? How this would determine the switch between viewController_A or viewController_B?

Comment: I mean if you have multiple tabviews then you can set its tag value

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITabBarControllerDelegate:

```
tabBarController.delegate = self
```

Then implement tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:

```
- (void)configureTabbarItem:(UITabBarItem *)item image:(UIImage *)image selectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage andTitle:(NSString *)title {
item.selectedImage = image;
item.image = selectedImage;
item.title = title;
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSArray *items = tabBarController.tabBar.items;
if (MyCondition) {
    [self configureTabbarItem: items[0]
                        image: myItemImageSel_B
                selectedImage: myItemImage_B
                     andTitle: myItemTitle_B];
}
else {
    [self configureTabbarItem: items[0]
                        image: myItemImageSel_A
                selectedImage: myItemImage_A
                     andTitle: myItemTitle_A];
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that code I have works fine, my question was how to segue to viewController_A or viewController_B according to myCondition, not sure if you are answering that.